# JDK Cross Compilation uses which version of JAX WS and JAXB?

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, jax-ws, cross-compiling

I have JDK 8 installed on my machine.
My code's POM has a Maven Compiler Plugin which uses source value as 1.7 and target as 1.8

I have JAXWS and JAXB dependency in my code. JDK 8 comes bundled with 2.2.9 version of JAXWS and JAXB.
JDK 7 with 2.2.4 version of same jars

On doing Cross Compilation with Maven Install, which version of JAXWS or JAXB jar will be used? How to find the version of JAXWS and JAXB jar?

If it uses 2.2.9 (corresponding to JDK 8), how to ensure it uses 2.2.4 (corresponding to JDK 7) version?

Let me know for more information.

Comment: Aren't the versions of the jars specified in your pom.xlm?

Comment: So I am migrating this from JDK 7 to JDK 8. Earlier it source and target values were JDK 6. And these two jars had a version of 2.1 . Now, if I do not specify versions of these jars, what will it take? Are you suggesting I have to explicitly mention versions?

Comment: They surely __must__ be specified somewhere. Maven doesn't just pick a version for you, at least I don't know of any such features.

Comment: Then I must try to understand how does Maven deal with rt.jar? Maven uses JDK just for running itself or for some other purpose as well? Need to figure this out.

Comment: Ah, I misread your question a bit, sorry. When it comes to the JDK specific libraries, I am not sure in the scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API of the jars

```
JAXWS-API,
JAXWS-IMPL,
JAXB-API,
JAXB-IMPL
```

has been made part of JDK with Java's version 6 and above.

What this actually means is that the API that is provided by these jars has been included within JDK's API. (To be precise, the API has been added to rt.jar)
While making the API part of JDK's API, the package name of the API was kept the same as their name was in the jars.

For example, suppose a WEB SERVICE project does not include any of the JAXWS jars through Maven. Then in any class write

```
  @WebMethod or 
  @WebService
```

and we do simply do ctrl+shift+o in STS or Eclipse, then the imports will automatically include their fully Qualified imports as

```
 import javax.jws.WebService; or
 import javax.jws.WebMethod;
```

Assuming that your packageExplorer is linked with Editor, doing ctrl+click on any one of these imports will lead to shifting the package explorer view to the location of the Class File. This will be somewhere within rt.jar of the JDK.

[image]

[image]

====
On the other hand, if we provide JAXWS jars through Maven with COMPILE scope, and repeating the same steps above will lead the package explorer view to show the class file to be within a JAXWS Jar, not the rt.jar of the JDK.

[image]

+++++++++++++++++++

+++++++++++++++++++

+++++++++++++++++++

This indicates that if JAXWS jars are made available as dependencies, JDK based JAXWS API is not used.